# Searching for great grandfather Arnold Kuhn who lived in Poland then Russia?

Tags: 19th-century, 20th-century, russia, poland

Is there any way to trace the origins of my great grandfather Arnold Kuhn?

He lived in poland and had a family there I believe towards the end of the 1800s and early 1900s.

At some point he moved alone to Russia and met my grandfather's mother, but they could not marry because his polish wife did not let him divorce. Consequently, my grandfather got his russian mother's name.

Arnold Kuhn died when my grandfather was still very young and they escaped at wartime to Finland where my grandfather grew up.

Is there any way to find the origins of my Polish great grandfather Arnold Kuhn and precisely where he came from?

We have a one photograph of him.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  Would you be able to use the **edit** button beneath your question to make it clear that the great grandfather you are seeking was named Arnold Kuhn.  If your great grandmother was born before 1914 (more than 100 years ago thus avoiding any privacy concerns) then I think it may be helpful if you can also include her name, date and place of birth/baptism and where in Russia she met him.

Comment: The photo might be helpful to include due to details in the photo. Ditto on PolyGeo's comments about clarification of whom you are looking for as your last sentence implies you are looking for the name of the man and where he was from but you name Arnold Kuhn above.

Comment: I hope you do not mind that I have edited your question to make it say clearly what I think you intended.  If not, feel free to roll back my edits and/or use the **edit** button to make the clarifications that @CRSouser and I are seeking.

Comment: Any other additional information such as his occupation, pieces of stories you may have heard about him, or any other 'tidbits' may help us help you.

Comment: "...lived in Poland" - context - Should the German territories added to Poland (aft WW1 or aft WW2) be included or excluded? (Kuhn is a German surname). "...escaped at wartime to Finland..." - which war? (WW1, Russian revolution, WW2); why Finland? (family connections? proximity? Finland was part of Russia until 1917).